# Checking if a Bigquery partition exists in Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, database-partitioning, airflow

My downstream Airflow BigQuery tasks rely on the presence of specific partitions in other tables (date partitions).
I know about the `BigQueryTableSensor` operator which checks if a table exists. Is there a simple way to check if a specific partition exists within that table? Effectively the operator should wait until those partitions exists before exiting successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the Airflow operators for BigQuery, and couldn't find one that verifies if a specific partition exists within a table in the [stable version](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/bigquery_sensor.html) of Airflow.

Recently, the Apache Airflow community has accepted a [merge request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/10218) that includes a function which checks the existence of a partition in a partitioned BigQuery table. The contribution is included in the [latest version](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/bigquery.html)

If this change is included in the next release, the new function may be called like this:

- Including the library

```py
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery import BigQueryTablePartitionExistenceSensor
```

- Calling the function

```py
    check_table_partition_exists = BigQueryTablePartitionExistenceSensor(                
        task_id="check_table_partition_exists",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        dataset_id=DATASET_NAME,
        table_id=TABLE_NAME,
        partition_id=PARTITION_NAME,
        )
```

You can check these [examples](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_bigquery_sensors.py) for more details.